# Scaling the dataset for train and test set (StandardScaler, Binarizer) with fit_transform and transform

Tags: php, python-3.x, scikit-learn, scaling, training-data

I would like to have a feedback if I am doing this correctly or not.
I have a binary classification problem to do so the first step I need to do is to scale the data.

I use StandardScaler with my features (all numerical continuous values) and Binarizer with my target variable (binary value).

My dataframe df is as below:

```
Date        Regime      Label   feat1    feat2       feat3      feat4
1960-09-01  Recession   1.0     -0.1     120         5555.2      0.006      
1960-10-01  Recession   1.0      0.6     140         6585.9     -0.001      
1960-11-01  Recession   0.0      0.0     90          4567       -0.002
...
```

Now I split train and test and I scale them in a different way, training set I use fit_transfomr (for both training features and training target) and for the test/validation set I use transform (for both validation features and validation target).

```
df_idx = df[df.Date == '1996-12-01'].index[0]

df_targets = df['Label'].values
df_features = df.drop(['Regime','Date','Label'], axis=1)

#scaling training features
df_training_features_ = df_features.iloc[:df_idx,:]
scaler=StandardScaler()
df_training_features = scaler.fit_transform(df_training_features_)

#scaling validation features
df_validation_features_ = df_features.iloc[df_idx:, :]
df_validation_features = scaler.transform(df_validation_features_)

#scaling training target
df_training_targets_ = df_targets[:df_idx]
lb = preprocessing.Binarizer(threshold = 0.5)
df_training_targets = lb.fit_transform(df_training_targets_.reshape(1, -1))[0]

#scaling validation target
df_validation_targets_ = df_targets[df_idx:]
df_validation_targets = lb.transform(df_validation_targets_.reshape(1, -1))[0]
```

After this I will then start with my hyperparameter tuning,feature selection and model construction but I am struggling a bit to get if this is right or wrong.

May you please confirm if this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Be careful!**

In your question you say that you will use `transform` for both training and validation targets. But in your code, for the validation targets, you are using `fit_transform`. You should use, as you said:

```
df_validation_targets = lb.fit_transform(df_validation_targets_.reshape(1, -1))[0]
```

By the way, I suppose do you have a test data? If not, fitting hyperparameters with your validation test, and obtaining the accuracy is not a good way to do it. You should change hyperparameters using validation data, and finally, test your model with test data that the model has never seen.

**PD:** I don't know if using fit_transform with only one sample works (try it)

Comment: Hi Alex, it is a TYPO, what I wanted to write is:  df_validation_targets = lb.transform(df_validation_targets_.reshape(1, -1))[0] (transfomr not fit_transform with validation_target). is it correct? Regarding the one sample thing, I guess you refer to df_validation_targets_.reshape(1, -1)[0] that is is because lb generate an array of array like array([[1,0,0,1]]) so i need to index at 0 regaring the hyperparameter I will answer below

Comment: Regarding the hyperparameter tuning after split and scale I will do:                            
kfold= model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=4) 
model=LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True, penalty='l1', random_state=42, solver='liblinear')
LR_penalty=model_selection.GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid= hyperparameters, cv=kfold, scoring='f1').fit(X=df_training_features, df_training_targets)  so the test set for me is the one within the cross validation phase..does it sound wrong? many thanks as usual ;)!

Comment: to be clearer validation set is for me the data I keep as out-of-sample, those my model sees as new, df_validation_targets will be compared then to model.predict(df_validation_features)

Comment: There are different ways to work to fit hyperparameters. Your way can be good too. But, you should be aware that you are fitting the hyperparameters only to your validation data. I agree that with cross validation your are like avoiding overfitting. As I said, it's can be correct, but care with overfittiing

Comment: do you have any reference with other ways of tuning hyperparameters?

Comment: Here is well documented what i mean for validation data: https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/143685. To obtain training, validation and test data use two times train_split. To tuning hyperparameters change parameters manually and observe accuracy, or use GridSearchCV.